# java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine

Tags: java, properties

I need to read a config file
I get this error while running the following code:

`java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine`

The file config.cfg is present and has r/w permissions.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Config   
{
 Properties configFile;
 public Config()
 {
configFile = new java.util.Properties();
try {           
  configFile.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().
  getResourceAsStream("config.cfg"));           
}catch(Exception eta){
     eta.printStackTrace();
}
}

public String getProperty(String key)
{

 String value = this.configFile.getProperty(key);       
 return value;

 }

}
```

### EDIT - Full Error

```
 [java] java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
 [java]     at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
 [java]     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
 [java]     at Config.<init>(Unknown Source)
 [java]     at ClosureBuilder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

### EDIT - Directory Structure

src

-> config.java

-> config.cfg

Comment: please provide the full error you are getting

Comment: I guess its not a able to read the file.

Comment: @OliverWeiler yes you were correct. Could you post as answer so I could accept?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to put your `config.cfg` in the same folder where your `.class` file lies.

Comment: More specifically you have to put it in the folder which is the head of the package structure. In this case there isn't a package structure so your answer is correct, but in general it wouldn't be. It would also be correct if he had used Class.getResourceAsStream(), but he hasn't.

Comment: below mentioned solution did not help me, I used "getResourceAsStream" not helped me. I made public static method and used FileInputStream

Answer (score 0):

The resource stream is being returned as null. The resource isn't where you think it is in the classpath.

Comment: check EDIT - Directory Structure

Comment: @cloudYturtle Putting it in the src directory is nice but it still isn't in the classpath, obviously, otherwise it would work. You haven't actually addressed that. Where is it at runtime? It needs to be in the root of the JAR file, or the root of a classpath item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your program is not able to find the `config.cfg` file.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.cfg")
```

The above call is returning `null`.

Try the below:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.cfg")
if(is !=null){
    configFile.load(is);
}
```

This change will not let your program fail. But also, if the file is not located, your property object `configFile` will not have any property from the file.

Comment: but I do need the data from config file.

Comment: check EDIT - Directory Structure

Answer (score 0):

Check the path what you are getting for your config using this.getClass().getResource("/");